# Submitting two forms with one submit button

Tags: html, jsp, struts

I have a requirement to submit two forms to different struts actions
on click of a single submit button.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

i think better submit using **AJAX**, so i can control the responses separately. what you say gurus ??

Comment: You can do the logic at application layer. Submit one form then call the other logic.

Answer (score 3):

Use Javascript or jQuery to do that.

On the Submit button where you want to submit both the forms write.

`jQuery('#form1').submit();
jQuery('#form2').submit();`

Comment: If you are using Ajax Submit than you can return from the Server success or failure.